# play sounds in array with delay

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play sounds from an array with time delay in between.

I've tried everything from while loops to using the delay function below, nothing seems to work.

The code plays only the first two strings on the array then it stops.

Please help me ):

```
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
var selectedSoundFileName : String = ""
var n : Int = 0

// array containing the sound files 
let playArray = ["base","snare","base","base","snare"]

// Button Press to start play sequence 

@IBAction func playSequence(_ sender: Any) {

    selectedSoundFileName =playArray[0]
    playSound()  

    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        selectedSoundFileName =playArray[1]
        playSound()
    }
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        selectedSoundFileName =playArray[2]
        playSound()
    }
}

func playSound() {
    let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: selectedSoundFileName, withExtension: "mp3")
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files `playArray[1]` and `playArray[2]` are scheduled to be played at the same time because both of your `when` values are the same. Only the block in the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` runs after the delay not the subsequent code. Try the following:

```
@IBAction func playSequence(_ sender: Any) {

 selectedSoundFileName =playArray[0]
 playSound()  

 let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
     selectedSoundFileName =playArray[1]
     playSound()
     let nextWhen = DispatchTime.now() + 1
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: nextWhen) {
        selectedSoundFileName =playArray[2]
        playSound()
     }
 }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The following code would be more scalable.

```
@IBAction func playSequence(_ sender: Any) {
    for index in 0..<playArray.count{
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + Double(index)//The sounds won't overlap as long as each sound's duration is 1 sec. If not you may have to add the duration of each sound to the delay instead of just a second.
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
          selectedSoundFileName = playArray[index]
          playSound()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Santhosh it worked like a charm (:

Comment: Sure Alex :) You can also keep the dispatch blocks outside and not nested like you did but increase the delay. Please see my edited answer.